# How can I pull/push data between gpu and cpu in tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cuda

I used a temporary tensor to store data in my customized gpu-based op. For debug purpose, I want to print the data of this tensor by traditional printf inside C++. How can I pull this gpu-based tensor to cpu and then print its contents.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *temporary* you mean `allocate_temp` instead of `allocate_output`, there is no way of fetching the data on the python side.

I usually  return the tensor itself during debugging so that a simple `sess.run` fetches the result. Otherwise, the only way to display the data is the traditional `printf` *inside* C++. Given your tensor is an output of your custom operation a `tf.Print` eases further debugging.

Example:

```cpp
Tensor temp_tensor;
OP_REQUIRES_OK(ctx, ctx->allocate_temp(DT_FLOAT, some.shape(), &temp_tensor));

float* host_memory = new float[some.NumElements()];
cudaMemcpy(host_memory, temp_tensor.flat<Dtype>().data(), some.NumElements() * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
std::cout << host_memory[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << host_memory[1] << std::endl;
std::cout << host_memory[2] << std::endl;
delete[] host_memory;
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. Yes, I want to output the data by traditional printf inside C++. Since it is a gpu-based tensor, I would like to know how to pull the data from gpu to cpu?

Comment: cumemcpy or `if(!threadIdx.x) printf` like in every cuda implementation.